# javascript - loop through ViewBag list

Tags: javascript, c#

i have a code that store data in a ViewBag list which will display on my select dropdown, the problem is my variable x is not recognizing inside the for loop, but when i changed it into index 0 it works. but when i changed into 'x' again it displays error and i can't figure it out why.

**error: the name 'x' does not exist in the current context**

```
   <script>

    
        var optionSy = '';
    
      
        {
            optionSy +=  '<select id="SyCode" class="term form-control" required> ';
            optionSy += '<option value="" selected hidden>Select School Year</option>';
            for (var x = 0; x < "@ViewBag.SysCode.Count"; x++) {
    
    
                optionSy += '<option value="' + "@ViewBag.SysCode[x].SyCode" + '"> @ViewBag.SysCode[x].SyDesc </option>';
    
                console.log(optionSy)
    
            }
            optionSy += '</select>';
        }
    
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Javascript executes in the browser. C# executes on the server. You seem to be trying to write a Javascript loop, but your data is server-side.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: `x` is part of your client-side Javascript code. `@ViewBag.SysCode[x].Sycode` is part of your server-side C# code. Therefore `x` doesn't exist in C# code.

Answer (score 0):

it's normal your variable will not be recognized since it's written as string

instead of using `@ViewBag.SysCode[x].SyCode"`

use the value of your variable `@ViewBag.SysCode["+x+"].SyCode"`